# WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 error while updating API definition

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

We are getting the below error while updating the API definition through publisher on WSO2 3.2.0 APIM. How to fix this issue:

TID: [-1234] [api/am/publisher] [2021-09-13 11:32:18,306] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.rest.api.util.exception.GlobalThrowableMapper} - An unknown exception has been captured by the global exception mapper. org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Couldn't find MIME boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryEsb6bxMwX39fG8Sb
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:60)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContextImpl.createAttachments(MessageContextImpl.java:284)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContextImpl.get(MessageContextImpl.java:79)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.tl.ThreadLocalMessageContext.get(ThreadLocalMessageContext.java:42)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getMultipartBody(AttachmentUtils.java:143)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.multipart.AttachmentUtils.getAttachments(AttachmentUtils.java:155)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Couldn't find MIME boundary: ------WebKitFormBoundaryEsb6bxMwX39fG8Sb
at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.initializeRootMessage(AttachmentDeserializer.java:140)
at org.apache.cxf.attachment.AttachmentDeserializer.initializeAttachments(AttachmentDeserializer.java:110)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:58)
... 54 more

Answer (score 0):

Is this issue occurring in the vanilla pack? Because this erroneous behavior is due to a known bug in the Tomcat version[1]. This issue has been identified and have fixed in the latest WUM updates.

Or else, you need to use a 9.0.34[2] bundle version and replace the appropriate jars. Also, new jars should be replaced in the bundle.info[3] as appropriate.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/issues/8029

[2] https://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/wso2/orbit/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-catalina-ha/9.0.34.wso2v1/

[3]
repository/components/default/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info

Comment: You can download the vanilla pack from https://wso2.com/api-management/previous-releases/ . But the fix can be taken via wum or update tool only. This requires subscription from WSO2 for APIM.

Comment: Hi Saranki, Thanks for your response. I have downloaded the WSO2 from https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/releases/download/v3.2.0. I have replaced jar(/plugins/tomcat-catalina-ha-9.0.34.wso2v1.jar) file and also updated the bundles.info and restarted the wso2 and tried to update the API definition, but still getting the same error. Kindly suggest how to fix this error.

Comment: Please share your API definition.

Comment: Hi Saranki, the API definition size is big. Where I will share. Kindly let me know

Comment: Hi Saranki, Where I will share the API definition file. Kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi Ram Kishan, you can add your API definition in google drive and share the link if possible.